# How to get a list of all HttpResponseStatus in netty?

Tags: java, netty

Looking at this class

https://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.1/api/index.html?org/jboss/netty/handler/codec/http/HttpResponseStatus.html

and looking at other classes in that package, is there no way to get the full list of HttpResponseStatus to iterate over?  Is there some util class or something to list all available values?

Comment: There's no simple way to retrieve all available pre-initialized `HttpResponseStatus` instances. You could use reflection, but it's probably not a good idea. I wonder why you need to get the full list though.  Could you elaborate?